# Having trouble in port forwarding

Tags: apache, tomcat, webserver, firewall, portforwarding

i want to connect my tomcat app from another computer through internet.I am using mobile hotspot as my router.
I installed Fwd:the port forwarding app and added following rule:
Protocol:BOTH
From : rmnet0    port : 8080
Target : 192.168.43.194   port:8080
but still when i am entering my ip address and 8080 port number than it is showing me following error:

### This site cant be reached 27.97.68.107 took too long to respond

Also when i am connecting my another computer with tomcat app through LAN,than it is working.
Please tell me where i am getting prolem ? Is there is any firewall problem ?

Actually, I am connecting my pc on which xampp tomcat is running with my mobile hotspot. By connecting with mobile hotspot my computer is accessible from internet. Now i want that another pc can access this tomcat app by internet.And for this i had used fwd:port forwarding app  and added follwing rule as stated above but still pc is not able to connect to tomcat app.

Comment: Are you trying to forward a port from your mobile device? Unless you are tunneling a connection (e.g. `stunnel`), this doesn't make a lot of sense. Can you explain a little more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for replying, i had added some more explanation. If yu need further details than tell me.

Comment: I think some more clarification is necessary: you have a server (running Tomcat) and you are using your mobile hot-spot as its connection to the internet? So it's just like a (possibly more traditional) cable/DSL router except it happens to be (a) using RF for internet and (b) running some mobile OS (iOS/Android/etc.)? Your client computer is connected to the internet by more traditional means, and you want to go from client -> mobile hotspot -> server, yes?

Comment: Yes i am running Tomcat server and using mobile hotspot as its connection to internet. This mobile is actually a android phone whose hotspot i am using.And yes i want that my client goes through this mobile hotspot to connect my tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

This can have a variety of reasons. Most likely is two things:

A) You indeed have to configure a firewall rule in your mobile hotspot router. Since I don’t know the device you should consult your manual.
B) If this is a cellular connection your MNO might forbid incoming connections from the internet to cellular clients. Can you retest the setup with another port and make sure this works? Best idea would be to use something like standard http (port 80).

BR,
TL

Comment: Thanks for reply,i did not understand option A,but for B i tried to use target port 80, but still it is not working.